# Need to fix my div elements to align lineup?

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin, divide

I'm working on a chatbox and trying to line up all my elements in one single div (code below), but it just breaks and appears under it. Why is this and how to fix it?

Any suggestions or examples would be very welcome.

[image]

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}   
    .chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .right {
    right:15px;
}
    /*............... chatbox ...............*/
    .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
    input[type=text] {
    width: 240px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
    /*......... crossfade on buttons .........*/

    .hover img{
    transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!--............ chatbox ..............-->

<div class="chatbox">

<!--........ emojis list ........-->

<div style="background:#2f2f2f;height:42px;"><a class="hover" href="emojis.htm"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" style="margin-left:-20px;"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" width="33" class="nohover" style="margin-left:-20px;"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" class="hover" style="margin-left:-20px;"></a>

<!--....... input message .......-->

<form><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''"></form>

<!--....... send button .......-->

<b style="margin-left:40px;size:16;line-height:2.9;"><i>Yummi is Typing...&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></b><a class="hover" href="send.htm"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button7.png" width="90" class="nohover"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90" class="hover"></a></div>

<!--....... chatlines .......-->

<div style="height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: Your html is very very messy, I'm not sure how you expect this to work with your code as is.

Comment: Don't use inline styling when you have a css file. It is much harder to maintain.

Comment: `width="33"` isn't working. width needs something like `px` or `em`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `display: flex` to your second `div`, like so:

```html
<div style="display: flex; background:#2f2f2f;height:42px;">
    <a class="hover" href="emojis.htm">
    <img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" style="margin- 
      left:-20px;">
    <img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" width="33" class="nohover" 
      style="margin-left:-20px;">
    <img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" class="hover" 
      style="margin-left:-20px;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with overflow and float. Try this:

Adjust the width of the input and everything is next to each other :)

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}   
    .chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .right {
    right:15px;
}
    /*............... chatbox ...............*/
    .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    overflow: hidden;
}
    input[type=text] {
    width: 240px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    background-color:transparent;
    float: left;
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
    /*......... crossfade on buttons .........*/

    .hover img{
    transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!--............ chatbox ..............-->

<div class="chatbox">

<!--........ emojis list ........-->

<div style="background:#2f2f2f;height:42px;"><a class="hover" href="emojis.htm"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" style="margin-left:-20px;"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" width="33" class="nohover" style="margin-left:-20px;"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" class="hover" style="margin-left:-20px;"></a>

<!--....... input message .......-->

<form><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''"></form>

<!--....... send button .......-->

<b style="margin-left:40px;size:16;line-height:2.9;"><i>Yummi is Typing...&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></b><a class="hover" href="send.htm"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button7.png" width="90" class="nohover"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90" class="hover"></a></div>

<!--....... chatlines .......-->

<div style="height:200px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use flexbox to create the wanted behaviour, in this case i made the div containing the input and the send button into a flexbox-row. you probably need to adjust the width a bit of the field below, cause the see-through button-text is slightly out of the black area now. Code is commented where i changed something.

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;   
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}   
    .chattext {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .right {
    right:15px;
}
    /*............... chatbox ...............*/
    .chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
    input[type=text] {
    width: 240px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
    .bubble {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:200px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
    /*......... crossfade on buttons .........*/

    .hover img{
    transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
/*this is the CSS for the div*/
.chatline {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;/*row-behaviour without breaking*/
}
```

```html
<!--............ chatbox ..............-->

<div class="chatbox">

<!--........ emojis list ........-->
<!--Added a class to this div below!-->
<div class="chatline" style="background:#2f2f2f;height:42px;"><a class="hover" href="emojis.htm"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" style="margin-left:-20px;"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" width="33" class="nohover" style="margin-left:-20px;"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" width="33" class="hover" style="margin-left:-20px;"></a>

<!--....... input message .......-->

<form><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''"></form>

<!--....... send button .......-->

<b style="margin-left:40px;size:16;line-height:2.9;"><i>Yummi is Typing...&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></b><a class="hover" href="send.htm"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button7.png" width="90" class="nohover"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90" class="hover"></a></div>

<!--....... chatlines .......-->

<div style="height:200px"></div>
```

Comment: to the editor: Thanks for the suggest but im not here to clean up OP's code, just to add a suggestion to solve the problem